# Larvel Notification Not working for custom email field

Tags: php, laravel

i want to send notification to my clinic owner, when a clinic is added by admin. The following is my code,but mails are not sending,please not that email field in my db is `clinicemail` . Following is my code in clinic controller

```
public function storeClinics(Request $request)
    {
        $postdata = $request->all();

        $api_key = Str::random(16);
        $checkApiKey = Clinic::where('api_key', $api_key)->first();
        if(!empty($checkApiKey)) {
            $api_key = Str::random(16);
        }

        $clinic = new Clinic;
        $clinic->clinicName=$postdata['user_name'];
        $clinic->clinicFname=$postdata['contact_fname'];
        $clinic->clinicLname=$postdata['contact_sname'];
        $clinic->clinicAddress=$postdata['contact_address'];
        $clinic->clinicCity=$postdata['contact_city'];
        $clinic->clinicState=$postdata['contact_state'];
        $clinic->clinicZip=$postdata['zip'];
        $clinic->clinicEmail=$postdata['email'];
        $clinic->clinicPhone=$postdata['phone'];
        $clinic->clinicURL=$postdata['clinic_website'];
        $clinic->clinicPub="no";
        $clinic->api_key=$api_key;
        $clinic->save();
        Notification::route('mail', $clinic->clinicEmail)->notify(new ClinicRegisteredNotification($clinic));

        return redirect('clinics');
    }
```

I have also created a notification named `ClinicRegisteredNotification` in notificcations folder and following is code

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class ClinicRegisteredNotification extends Notification {

    public function __construct($clinic) {
        $this->user = $clinic;
    }

    public function via($notifiable) {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->success()
            ->subject('Welcome')
            ->line('Dear ' . $this->clinic->clinicName . ', we are happy to see you here.')
            ->line('Please tell your friends about us.');
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you testing your email? How is your email configured in your .env or config files?

Comment: Am getting email for my another controller ,i mean site user

Answer (score 0):

In the `ClinicRegisteredNotification`, try to add a protected attribute before the `__construct($clinic)` method and change the line in the constructor.

The beginning of `ClinicRegisteredNotification` should be this:

```
class ClinicRegisteredNotification extends Notification {

protected $clinic;

public function __construct($clinic) {
    $this->clinic = $clinic;
}
```

This should solve the issue.